# Problema com modal no Laravel e vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, modal

Olá a todos!Eu estou trabalho com uma aplicação CRUD no laravel e Vue.js e no momento estou enfrentando o seguinte problema eu criei um modal para fazer update numa tabela, o modal faz a reaquisição dos objetos corretamente nos campus de input, o problema e que ao clicar em salvar o modal não desaparece, não salva e o que e mais estranho e que não aparece nenhum  código erro no console, estou completamente sem referencia de qual seja o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
new Vue({
    el: '#tableprod',

created: function () {
    this.getProdutos();
},
data () {
    return {
      produtos:[],
      fillproduto:{'id':'','nome_pro':'','descricao_pro':'' },  
    }
  },
methods:{
     editprod:function(produto){
     this.fillproduto.id= produto.id;
     this.fillproduto.nome_pro=produto.nome_pro;
     this.fillproduto.descricao_pro=produto.descricao_pro;
     $('#edit').modal('show');
     },
       updat:function(id){
       var url='updateprod/'+ id;
       axios.put(url, this.fillproduto).then(response=>{
       this.getProdutos();
       this.fillproduto={'id':'','nome_pro':'','descricao_pro':'' };
       $('#edit').modal('toggle');
       });
       },
     }
```

**Rota usada no axios para update**

```
|        | PUT      | admin/updateprod/{id}        | componet_2.produtos | App\Http\Controllers\ProdutoController@updateProd     | web
```

Comment: Um dúvida: a requisição traz uma resposta de status 200? Digo, se você for no Inspecionar Elemento e entrar na aba de Network, confere lá se está retornando com status 200.

Comment: Olá Matheus Cristian! Esta trazendo status 500.

Comment: Richard Carlos, acredito que como o resultado está dando 500 (erro interno no servidor), não esteja chamando a função pelo "then" você pode criar um "catch" logo após para tratar o erro e fechar o modal: `.catch(error => { $('#edit').modal('toggle'); })`. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Valeu pelo salve! Matheus Cristian

Comment: ;) Qualquer coisa, estou por aqui, fica bem.